# question about two SAXParser in a class

Tags: java, sax, xml-parsing

I have two sax parser as follows:

```
 try {
                SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
                SAXParser parser1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();


                parser.parse(new File("G:\\Documents\\posts.xml"), this);
                parser1.parse(new File("G:\\Documents\\comments.xml"), this);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the question is that when the handler startElement is called, how do I check whether this is from parser1 or parser2? I am assuming that uri and localName is used, but how?

Comment: It would be easier to just use two separate handlers...

Comment: You should use separate callbacks. Its just like having 1 resultset parser while using JDBC to query different entities, which in theory is possible but not recommended.

Comment: how can you create two separate handlers? sample code maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using two handlers. As a trivial example (you'll have to fill in the details):

```
class SaxClass {
   Handler h1;
   Handler h2;

   //...stuff

   method() {
      h1 = new Handler();
      h2 = new Handler();

      try {
         SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
         SAXParser parser1 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();

         parser.parse(new File("G:\\Documents\\posts.xml"), h1);
         parser1.parse(new File("G:\\Documents\\comments.xml"), h2);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   class Handler extends DefaultHandler {
      // Implementation
   }
}
```

[It doesn't look like](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) there's a way to find the parser that generated the event.

Comment: then when you call parse, you should specify which handler to use right.. not this? I think you need to edit your code above

Comment: hmm...it complaints that it is not applicaple and is asking me to change it to HandlerBase?

Comment: What was your `this` extending/implementing?

Comment: I think it was DefaultHandler

Comment: Ok, I didn't look at the doc close enough. There's two `parse`s: one for a `DefaultHandler` and one for a `HandlerBase`. Up to you which one is better for your purposes. My code now has `DefaultHandler` since that was what you mentioned.

Comment: Are they the same? What's the difference between them

Comment: Read the doc for the details, but `HandlerBase` is deprecated because it uses a deprecated interface. It was a SAX1 class. SAX2 uses `DefaultHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to differentiate two content handlers based on the same class, you should construct two instances of the content handler, and pass a constructor parameter to differentiate the two, (or setter method). Save that information in the content handler as fields, and refer to them to differentiate.